# Can't View *MANAGE PRODUCTS* Page... Is This a Magento Cache Issue?

Tags: cache, products-management, management

I have an issue where my screen/page seems to be caching, so I can't view existing products...

[image: Screen Shot of the Problem]

If I clear the Cache in Cache Management it works perectly until I create or edit a product and also if I use CMD + R to refresh (on a mac) or Ctrl + F5 to force refresh (on a windows PC) it works after a few attempts (sometimes 3 sometimes 10).

Not sure whats causing it, any ideas of where to look would be really helpful

Thanks

Comment: as a side note : when I create a new product or edit an existing product, then the "refresh cache" notice comes back up and the problem arrises once again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not a caching issue. You wrote a bug in some module which is called.

Track the bug down with the help of this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/217